# Use candy machine in anchor program

Tags: anchor, metaplex, candymachine

Are there examples of calling candy machine and candy guard prgoram from an anchor program?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [sugar cli](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/sugar/tree/main) code from metaplex, it calls the anchor program internally.
Here is link: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/sugar/blob/main/src/guard/add.rs for one of the calls.